# how to include industry fixed effects in a panel linear model (plm) based on industry codes in R

Tags: r, controls, regression, panel, plm

**Period**: 
2005 until 2011

**Independent variable** (is constant over the whole period):
`famfirm05` = dummy (equals 1 if family owns >= 5% of the company)

**Dependent variable**:
Return on assets

**Industry fixed effects:** 
Based on industry codes `sic`

`gvkey` = company id

`crisis` = dummy (equals 1 if year >= 2008)

This is how my data frame `pdata1` looks like:

```
    pdata1 <- pdata.frame(data_panel, index=c("gvkey","t"))

       year t gvkey famfirm05 lag_investment crisis  sic
1004-2 2005 1  1004         0     0.07637079      0 5080
1004-3 2006 2  1004         0     0.11489159      0 5080
1004-4 2007 3  1004         0     0.09772772      0 5080
1004-5 2008 4  1004         0     0.11211958      1 5080
1004-6 2009 5  1004         0     0.08628114      1 5080
...
```

This is how my output for the pooling, between, within and random model looks like:

```
ols <- plm(ROA ~  
           + famfirm05*crisis
           + lag_investment
           , data=subset(pdata), model = "pooling")
between <- update(ols, model = "between")
within <- update(ols, model = "within")
walhus <- update(ols, model = "random", random.method = "walhus", random.dfcor = 3)

library("texreg")
screenreg(list(ols = ols, between = between, within = within, 
               walhus = walhus),
          digits = 5, omit.coef = "(Intercept)")

==============================================================================
                      ols             between       within          walhus        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
famfirm05            0.01148 *       0.10879 *                     0.01064    
                    (0.00532)       (0.04770)                     (0.00712)   
crisis              -0.01662 ***     0.12100 *    -0.01742 ***    -0.01732 ***
                    (0.00403)       (0.04875)     (0.00324)       (0.00324)   
lag_investment       0.01183        -0.04228       0.06096 ***     0.04252 ***
                    (0.00948)       (0.02290)     (0.01042)       (0.00950)   
famfirm05:crisis    -0.00279        -0.20953 *     0.00189         0.00051    
                    (0.00776)       (0.10085)     (0.00623)       (0.00623)   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
R^2                  0.00528         0.01250       0.01465         0.01002    
Adj. R^2             0.00468         0.00897      -0.18591         0.00943    
Num. obs.             6665            1125          6665            6665          
==============================================================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
> 
> car::vif(ols)
       famfirm05           crisis   lag_investment famfirm05:crisis 
        1.884555         1.374256         1.011674         2.252301
```

**1) I would like to include industry fixed effects in the OLS model.**

I know that it is possible to create industry dummies for the `sic` variable from the `pdata1` data frame.

**2) Does one of you also know how to potentially include the states of incorporation of the companies as state fixed effects?**

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

1)
If you want to include industry fixed effects, include variable `sic` as a factor in your model, like so for the OLS (pooling) model:

```
plm(ROA ~ famfirm05*crisis + lag_investment + factor(sic), data = pdata, model = "pooling")
```

2)
To include state fixed effects, you would need a variable which contains the firms' state. I cannot see such a variable from the data you show. Let's assume such a variable is available and is called `state`. We would include it the same was as we did for the industry fixed effect - as a factor, e.g. in the pooling model:

```
plm(ROA ~ famfirm05*crisis + lag_investment + factor(sic) + factor(state), data = pdata, model = "pooling")
```